# Multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-operator

I'm trying to make multiple conditions:

```
adae <- adae %>%
  mutate(AREPIOD = if_else((AESTDTC >= AP01SDT) & (AESTDTC <= AP01EDT), 1, 
                           if_else((AESTDTC >= AP02SDT) & (AESTDTC <= AP02EDT), 2, "")))
```

But I get the error:

```
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! Can't combine `true` <double> and `false` <character>.
```

Please help. Where is the problem?

Comment: I get the same error with `if_else(TRUE, 1, "")`. A column in a data.frame can only only one data type. You seem to want to combine numeric values 1 & 2 with a character value "". Is that really what you want? Or maybe you want `NA` for the last case? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike base R's `ifelse`, the *type* of the "true" and "false" arguments in dplyr's `if_else` must agree. In your case, you are trying to get your inner `if_else` to return *either* a number `2`, or the empty string `""`. Since the output of `if_else` is a vector, it is unclear whether you want a numeric vector or a character vector.

Base R's `ifelse` will simply convert the numbers to characters here:

```r
ifelse(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 2, "")
#> [1] "2" "2" ""
```

But this may not be what you wanted. You can't do any maths on the output, for example, since the "2" values in the above are character strings. `if_else` forces you to decide what you mean, to avoid such ambiguity:

```r
if_else(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 2, "")
#> Error in `if_else()`:
#> ! Can't combine `true` <double> and `false` <character>.
#> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If we really want a character vector, we need to explicitly make the 2 appear as a character string for `if_else` to work:

```r
if_else(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), "2", "")
#> [1] "2" "2" ""
```

My guess though is that in your case, you want a numeric vector, with `""` representing a missing value. It can be difficult to get away from this if you are used to spreadsheets, but missing numeric values in R *must* be recorded as `NA`, otherwise the vector gets converted to the wrong type. So it might be better to have:

```r
if_else(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 2, NA)
#> [1]  2  2 NA
```

In your case, therefore, you need to decide whether you want

```r
adae <- adae %>%
  mutate(AREPIOD = if_else((AESTDTC >= AP01SDT) & (AESTDTC <= AP01EDT), "1", 
                           if_else((AESTDTC >= AP02SDT) & (AESTDTC <= AP02EDT), "2", "")))
```

or

```r
adae <- adae %>%
  mutate(AREPIOD = if_else((AESTDTC >= AP01SDT) & (AESTDTC <= AP01EDT), 1, 
                           if_else((AESTDTC >= AP02SDT) & (AESTDTC <= AP02EDT), 2, NA)))
```

Either will work, but the type of output is up to you.